# Using a specific path for generated PDF files with jsPDF

Tags: jquery, jspdf

**Is it, with jsPDF, possible to use a specific path for the generated pdf?**

I'm using this for the saving part:

```
 pdf.save(path);
```

But editing the path, will only rename the name of the file. So if I for example use "pdf/pdf.pdf" as a path, the pdf file will simply be named "pdf-pdf.pdf"

Answer (score 1):

No, javascript does not support saving files in custom locations for security reasons.